# iPadOS 17.1 SwiftUI DatePicker with onTapGesture unexpected behaviour

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, swiftui-ontapgesture

We have met a problem with iPadOS 17.1.

We have a normal `DatePicker` to choose the date, but in the meantime, we added an `onTapGesture` to it and did something.

With the previous version 17.0, when we click the `DatePicker`, the calendar view is poping up and let's us choose the date. But when we updated to 17.1, the calendar is not shown with a normal click, only a long press gesture will trigger it.

Here is the sample code:

```swift
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("test", selection: .constant(Date()), displayedComponents: .date)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("on tap")
            }
    }
}
```

The expectation is the calendar should be shown when the picker is tapped.

Comment: My just-updated app has the same behavior! Interestingly, if a DatePicker includes .date and .hourAndMinute for the displayedComponents, the hour and minute drop list works as expected, but tapping the date selection does not display the calendar.

Comment: Follow-on with my comment, this behavior is for an iPhone app with iOS 17.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `DatePicker` and `onTapGesture` are fighting to be first, which gives an undefined behaviour that could be different at any time. It is probably better to use [`.simultaneousGesture(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/simultaneousgesture(_:including:)) in this situation.

For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let newGesture = TapGesture().onEnded {
        // Do your work here
        print("on simultaneous tap \(Int.random(in: 1...99))")
    }
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("test", selection: .constant(Date()), displayedComponents: .date)
            .simultaneousGesture(newGesture)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This comes with the same behavior. The tap action is executed, but the calendar will not pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different approach to do something after the date has been selected, using `.onChange(..)`, instead of relying on the other tap guesture.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("test", selection: $selection, displayedComponents: .date)
            .onChange(of: selection) {
                print("---> do your thing here")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But that's not what we expected. We have some logic relying on the onTapGesture before the date is changed.

Comment: Then you need a custom binding that does the work. It is probably good to show what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. As a dirty workaround, you can programatically call `sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)` of `UIButton` in `UIDatePicker` that is internally used in `DatePicker`, in `onTapGesture()`.

You can use whatever to get the UIButton, but if you use [SwiftUI Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect), the code would look like this:

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
@_spi(Advanced) import SwiftUIIntrospect

struct DatePickerIssueWorkaround: View {
    @Weak private var datePicker: UIDatePicker?

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            DatePicker("test", selection: .constant(Date()), displayedComponents: .date)
                .onTapGesture {
                    let button = datePicker?.findViews(of: UIButton.self).first
                    button?.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
                }
                .introspect(.datePicker, on: .iOS(.v15...)) { datePicker in
                    self.datePicker = datePicker
                }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            print("on tap")
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func findViews<TargetView: UIView>(of type: TargetView.Type) -> [TargetView] {
        var foundViews = [TargetView]()
        for subview in subviews {
            if let subviewOfType = subview as? TargetView {
                foundViews.append(subviewOfType)
            }
            foundViews.append(contentsOf: subview.findViews(of: TargetView.self))
        }
        return foundViews
    }
}
```